# Handling Callback from JSONP

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to handle a JSONP Callback, I have the following JavaScript

```
var URL = "http://localhost:8000/returndata?s=testjsonp";
function alertResponse(data, status) {
    alert("data: " + data + ", status: " + status);
}

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "alertResponse",
    complete: alertResponse
});
```

When a response to the server is made it returns the following JSON:
Note the double quotes.

```
"alertResponse({'status':'OK'})"
```

I'm not sure how I can handle this with my javascript.

Can someone help me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

It returns JSONP response treated as string and encoded using JSON.

In other words, **the answer from the server is incorrect**.

### Solution

Instead of:

```js
"alertResponse({'status':'OK'})"
```

it should be:

```js
alertResponse({'status':'OK'})
```

### The "Why?" part

**The point of JSONP** is to include it using `<script>` tag, so the returned response **must be correct JavaScript**, calling some callback function (usually specified by one of the GET params during calling remote server) that is supposed to **process retrieved data**.

Comment: Is there anyway to clean the returned JSON to proper JSON?

Comment: @SandeepBansal: The proper way is to do it on the server.

Comment: OK thanks for that I'll have to read up the server side docs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SandeepBansal: The purpose of JSONP is mostly to have a walkaround for Same Origin Policy, and it is used mostly to get something from other server. As long as you call the same server (with the same domain), I can give you a solution. But if you want cross-origin solution, then you should definitely try to fix this server side first. You are welcome.

Comment: Thanks but it's a different origin, that's why I have to go through the JSONP route.